# Create App without copying `/usr/lib` in Julia

Tags: linux, julia, executable

I am trying to create an app in Julia using the PackageCompiler package. However, during the process the `bundle_julia_libraries` function is called and executes `cp(julia_libdir(), app_libdir; force=true)` with `julia_libdir()` resolving effectively as `dirname(abspath(Libdl.dlpath("libjulia")))`.

On one of my machines this ends up being along the lines of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` which is sufficiently small to not cause problems. However on another machine this resolves to `/usr/lib` which is causing problems. (specifically in my case `/usr/lib/cups` contains some files that the dev user doesn't have permission to copy).

Is there any way to override or otherwise modify the app compilation process so as to only include a subset of `/usr/lib` (for instance, just `/usr/lib/libjulia.so*` and `/usr/lib/julia/*` would probably be sufficient) into the resulting build directory?

Is there some more idiomatic way to distribute an application written in Julia that doesn't require precompilation (e.g. pip install creating an executable shebang powered python script)?

Any help would be appreciated!